# OpenAPI (aka Swagger) in Azure Functions V2

Tags: azure-devops, swagger, azure-functions, openapi

I'm creating a V2 Function App and want to use Swagger/Open API for docs, however it is not yet supported in the Azure Portal for V2 Functions.

Any suggestions on how I can use Swagger with V2 Functions in VSTS to create the docs on each build?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**TL;DR** - Use the NuGet package to render Open API document and Swagger UI through Azure Functions.

---

**UPDATE** (2021-06-04)

Microsoft recently [announced the OpenAPI support on Azure Functions](https://aka.ms/azfunc-openapi-support) during the //Build event.

The *Aliencube* extension has now been archived and no longer supported. Please use this [official extension](https://aka.ms/azfunc-openapi).

As of today, it's in preview. Although it's in preview, it has more features than the Aliencube one.

> **Acknowledgement 2**: I am still maintaining the official one.

---

Microsoft hasn’t officially started supporting Open API (or Swagger) yet. But there is a community-driven NuGet package currently available:

[Nuget > Aliencube.AzureFunctions.Extensions.OpenApi](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aliencube.AzureFunctions.Extensions.OpenApi/)

And here’s the blog post for it:

[Introducing Swagger UI on Azure Functions](https://devkimchi.com/2019/02/02/introducing-swagger-ui-on-azure-functions/)

Basically its usage is similar to Swashbuckle — using decorators. And it supports both Azure Functions V1 and V2.

> **Acknowledgement 1**: I am the owner of the NuGet package.

Comment: Recently, I’ve been getting an error: “An item with the same key has already been added. Key: 400”. I got it to work before and it was excellent 

Comment: @Albert Can you raise an issue on my GitHub repository?

Comment: This is a great resource, but in my case I needed to apply a custom security schema (authorization bearer token) and this tool dont let you implement it

Comment: @RodrigoRamírez That needs to be implemented.

Comment: There now seems to be an [official MS version of this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-openapi-extension/blob/main/docs/enable-open-api-endpoints.md) currently in preview. It actually looks spookily similar?

Comment: @Liam Yes, I'm managing both. The Aliencube one was transferred to the MS one and will be archived, once the MS one is officially announced.

Answer (score 7):

There is **official** library [Azure Functions OpenAPI Extension](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-openapi-extension). It is still in **preview**, but looks great.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone looking into this, Microsoft still hasn't added Open API support for Azure Functions +v2 and there hasn't been any major movement toward it.

I faced this same issue recently and I found a pretty good solution.
If you aren't aware yet, check this out: https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag

NSwag is a toolchain that integrates with .NET to produce the Open API documentation and UI, but also generates the respective API clients for you.
I've used this tool for the past 2 years when working with Angular and .NET apps, it saves a lot of time and seamlessly integrates with my whole development workflow.

For Azure Functions +v2, a contributor created a generator that in less than 10 lines of code, allow us to expose the Swagger endpoint for an Azure Function class:
https://github.com/Jusas/NSwag.AzureFunctionsV2

Now, if you design HTTP-Triggered Functions using DI, grouping related operations under the same class and leveraging model binding, you might not even need to apply any custom decorator, it just works!
Here's an example of how one real API would look like:
[image: API + Swagger example]

*(ignore the base class. It is part of a personal pattern I follow, unrelated to Swagger)*

And this is how it looks like using a swagger UI:
[image: Swagger UI example]

Answer (score 0):

Can you drop your V2 Function to run on v1 of the runtime by starting over with a blank function app first?

The MSDN documents for [Create an OpenAPI definition for a function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-openapi-definition) (with a date of 11/2018 interestingly enough) example states:

> By default, the function app you create uses version 2.x of the
>   runtime. You must set the runtime version back to 1.x before you
>   create your function.

But one can't just move the setting to 1:

> To pin your function app to the version 1.x runtime, choose ~1 under
>   Runtime version. This switch is disabled when you have functions in
>   your app.

Which implies one must create the Function app, publish/create it, set it to V1 and then put in a function before adding a function app.